# /etc/default/grub: line 60: terminal_output: command not found

Tags: centos, grub, grub2-mkconfig

I am using centos7 when I run command `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` I get error **/etc/default/grub: line 60: terminal_output: command not found**
The lines after 60 of /etc/default/grub file are:

```
terminal_output console
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
set timeout_style=menu
set timeout=5
else
set timeout=5
fi
# END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
```

Comment: What is the `terminal_output` command/function supposed to do and where is it being declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By mistake I ran this command `grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/default/grub` this replaced `/etc/default/grub` file with `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. So I manually changed `/etc/default/grub` to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

and now it works fine.